# How to detect when a digital keyboard is displayed (on mobile)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mobile

I'm running into a very annoying issue.

I have a html canvas that is full screen. When changing the screen size it detects that the screen size has changed and automatically re-scales the canvas to the 'new' full screen.

I put a  object into the canvas (basically a text input field).

On mobile when clicking on this object the virtual keyboard pops-out and apparently changes the screen size. By doing this the canvas scales to the 'new' screen size.

I want to ignore the automatically scale function when a digital keyboard pops out.

Is there any way to detect when a digital keyboard is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of to fix this is to stop the page from resizing if there is a digital keyboard displayed:

```
$(function() {
    var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
    $("html, body").css({"width":w,"height":h});
});
```